# Mapping XOR expression into K map

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

I know any SOP and POS can be minimised directly with the help of KMAP and there is no difficulty in mapping each Boolean product or sum term into KMAP. However what if the boolean expression is in the form of XOR
Can someone help me map 
[(A + B) XOR (BC) XOR (C) ] into a 3 variable K Map which is a function of A,B and C.
I know how to minimise  it using basic Boolean algebra , but K Map minimisation help is required for above expression .

Comment: Have you considered trying to draw a 2x2 KMAP for an XOR gate and and XNOR gate, and seeing if you could glean a pattern from that and then see if that pattern extends to a 3x3 KMAP? Maybe you could unravel the mystery from there. I find it helpful to label the 'grouped columns' and 'grouped rows' by what Boolean primitive they express (i.e. A and /A, B and /B, C and /C, etc.)

Comment: Could you please explain further ? I solved it using a mix of truth table and then KMAP , but was looking for something better .

Comment: Sorry, can't do your homework for you. Write down all your work in the question, and what you came up with as an answer on your own. And try and understand how KMAPs are, at some level, just a way of visualizing truth tables.

Comment: I've never heard of 'naturally' mapping XOR logic onto a KMAP, incidentally... your approach of converting it to SOP or a truth table as an intermediate step is probably just fine, frankly.